# How to call a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Nodo{
    Nodo *siguiente,*anterior;
    char* Nombre,*Curso;
    int carnet;
    Nodo(){
        siguiente=anterior=NULL;
    }
};
struct ListaCircular{
    Nodo *PrimerNodo,*UltimoNodo;
    ListaCircular(){
        PrimerNodo->siguiente=PrimerNodo->anterior=UltimoNodo;
        UltimoNodo->siguiente=UltimoNodo->anterior=PrimerNodo;
    }
    void RegistrarUnaInclusion();
    void BuscarInclusion();
    void EliminarInclusion();
    void RechazarAprobarInclusion();
    void MostrarInclusiones();

};
    void ListaCircular::RegistrarUnaInclusion(){
    ListaCircular *Lista=new ListaCircular();
    PrimerNodo->Curso="EstructurasDeDatos";
    PrimerNodo->Nombre="Roberto";
    PrimerNodo->carnet=201243031;
    UltimoNodo->Curso="POO"; 
    UltimoNodo->Nombre="Luis";
    UltimoNodo->carnet=201233212;
    Nodo *Nuevo;
    char *Nom,*Cur;
    long Car;
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del estudiante que va a registrar"<<endl;
    cin>>Nom;
    Nuevo->Nombre=Nom;
    cout<<"Ingrese el care del estudiante "<<Nuevo->Nombre<<endl;
    cin>>Car;
    Nuevo->carnet=Car;
    cout<<"Ingrese el curso al que desea hacer la inclusion"<<endl;
    cin>>Cur;
    Nuevo->Curso=Cur;
}
```

When i try to run my code it sends me an ERROR message, and says something like that:

undefined reference to `_WinMain@16' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I don´t know if it could be for not having a "main" function, and another thing, how can i call the function "RegistrarUnaInclusion" to make it work?

Comment: Isn't the first lesson in a C++ book, "Every program needs an `int main()` function"?

Comment: Yes, but theres a way to make void ListaCircular::RegistrarUnaInclusion() as the main function, and i dont know how to do it

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: No, there isn't a way, and it wouldn't have any sense. Maybe you are used to other languages where this makes sense (and I may just not now those languages), but in C++ it really doesn't. You just need a `main()` or your program won't be legal C++.

Comment: Mmm well thank you @AndyProwl =), and for the others this is my 2° day learning c++, so thank for the negative votes =D

Comment: @RobertoHernandez [OT] All other problems of this code aside, you are treating the `Nombre` and `Curso` members of your `Nodo` struct *very* *very* incorrectly. This simple program might work, but any larger program with this kind of linked-list node in it will run into horrible runtime problems and crashes due to the fact that you don't actually allocate memory for your members in your nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don´t know if it could be for not having a "main" function

Well, yes, that's kind of a problem. Each program *must* have a `main()` function. Where else would the execution start from?

> how can i call the function "RegistrarUnaInclusion" to make it work?

`RegistrarUnaInclusion` is a *member function* of class `ListaCircular`. Therefore, you need an instance (an object) of that class to invoke that member function on:

```
ListaCircular l;
l.RegistrarUnaInclusion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to search your error in Google? I'm recommending you to follow [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) tutorial before start to write your next C++ program. Because I think your are missing general knowledge of programming.

In simply you must need a main method for any program to run. Compiler use main method to identify the entry point of the program. (not only C++ also most of the other languages) So here error is your program **doesn't have a main method**. And recommend to read [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) about main method